# Silverstripe looping has_many inside template

Tags: php, silverstripe

I want to loop my products on template using `has_many` relation but somthing am doing wrong. First i create DataObject `Product` with `has_one` and create ModelAdmin for adding new products. After that i create ProductPage model and controller and ProductPage template where i loop products.

**Data Object:**

```
<?php

class Product extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'Varchar',
        'Description' => 'HTMLText',
        'Price' => 'Decimal'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Photo' => 'Image',
        'ProductPage' => 'ProductPage'
    );

    public function getCMSFields()
    {
        $fields = FieldList::create(TabSet::create('Root'));

        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Main', array(
            TextField::create('Name'),
            HtmlEditorField::create('Opis'),
            NumericField::create('Price'),
            UploadField::create('Photo')
        ));

        return $fields;
    }

}
```

ProductPage:

```
class ProductPage extends Page
{
    private static $has_many = array(
        'Products' => 'Product'
    );
}

class ProductPage_Controller extends Page_Controller
{

}
```

**Template:**

```
<% if $Products %>
    <% loop $Products %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>$Name</h3>
        </div>
    <% end_loop %>
<% else %>
    No product found
<% end_if %>
```

Am get all time `No product found` but i have products in database.

What can be problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the name you used for your relation in your template. Eg. you name your relation `RelationName`, then that is what you use to access the relation in code or templates.

```
private static $has_many = array( 'RelationName' => 'ObjectName' );
```

So in your case, use `Products`:

```
<% if $Products %>
    <% loop $Products %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>$Name</h3>
        </div>
    <% end_loop %>
<% else %>
    No product found
<% end_if %>
```

You'll need to ensure that the Products are actually linked to your Product-Page. Just creating them in a `ModelAdmin` won't establish a relation for you… I suggest you use a `GridField` for that. You can add the following code to your `ProductPage` to do that:

```
public function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $gridConfig = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create();

    /** @var GridField $gridField */
    $gridField = GridField::create(
        'Products',
        _t('ProductPage.has_many_Products', 'Products'),
        $this->Products(),
        $gridConfig
    );

    $gridField->setModelClass('Product');

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $gridField);

    return $fields;
}
```

If you want to create Products via `ModelAdmin` and not link them to `ProductPage`, you can skip the entire `has_many` relation and just output all Products in a method of `ProductPage`:

```
public function Products()
{
    return Product::get();
}
```

Comment: I try also that and dont work.i just miss to add 's' on the end.

Comment: What about if i have relation with categories and whant to show cat id in that loop ?

Comment: @Zend I suggest you create a new question for that